# How to count using input strings?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Hi I am trying to count max value in given problem using an input string. 
Problem decscription:
Given two months x and y, where y > x, find the hashtag name that has increased the number of tweets the most from month x to month y. We have already written code in your code template that reads the x and y values from the keyboard.  Ignore the tweets in the months between x and y, so just compare the number of tweets at month x and at month y. Report the hashtag name, the number of tweets in months x and y. Ignore any hashtag names that had no tweets in either month x or y. You can assume that the combination of hashtag and month is unique.  Print the result to the terminal output using println. For the above small example data set the output should be the following:

```
Input       x = 200910, y = 200912

Output  hashtagName: mycoolwife, countX: 1, countY: 500
Data Fomrat:

Token type  Month   count   Hash Tag Name

hashtag 200910  2   Babylove

hashtag 200911  2   babylove

hashtag 200912  90  babylove
```

My attempt:

```
// Load the input data and split each line into an array of strings
val twitterLines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/ashhall1616/bdc_data/twitter-small.tsv")
val twitterdata = twitterLines.map(_.split("\t"))

// Each month is a string formatted as YYYYMM
val x = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("x month: ")
val y = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("y month: ")

val matchmonth= twitterdata.map(r => (r(0)== x ,r(0)==y, r(2), r(3))).sortBy(_._3, false)
if(matchmonth.(r => (r(0))) < matchmonth.(r => (r(1)))
   {
       val ht1 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1)
       val ht2 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1,2)
           println("[" + ht1 + "," + ht2 + "]")
   }
```

errors getting:

```
 val matchmonth= twitterdata.map(r => (r(0)== x ,r(0)==y, r(2), r(3))).sortBy(_._3, false)
matchmonth: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Boolean, Boolean, String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[20] at sortBy at <console>:32
scala> if(matchmonth.(r => (r(0))) < matchmonth.(r => (r(1)))
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '(' found.
if(matchmonth.(r => (r(0))) < matchmonth.(r => (r(1)))
              ^
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '(' found.
if(matchmonth.(r => (r(0))) < matchmonth.(r => (r(1)))
                                         ^
scala>    {
     |        val ht1 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1)
     |        val ht2 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1,2)
     |            println("[" + ht1 + "," + ht2 + "]")
     |    }
<console>:36: error: (Boolean, Boolean, String, String) does not take parameters
              val ht1 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1)
                                              ^
<console>:36: error: (Boolean, Boolean, String, String) does not take parameters
              val ht1 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1)
                                                    ^
<console>:37: error: (Boolean, Boolean, String, String) does not take parameters
              val ht2 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1,2)
                                              ^
<console>:37: error: (Boolean, Boolean, String, String) does not take parameters
              val ht2 = matchmonth.map(r => (r(2), r(3))).take(1,2)
```

can someone have a look what is wrong here?

Comment: what is that for a construct `matchmonth.(r => (r(0))) < matchmonth.(r => (r(1))` ?  I mean, what is `.(` in your opinion in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read a few articles on Spark SQL and the DataFrame API.

matchmonth is a DataFrame (if it helps you can think of this as an SQL table). Using it in an if statement makes no sense. It is also very useful to name the columns. e.g.

```
val twitterdata = twitterLines.map(_.split("\t")).toDF("tokenType", "month", "count", "hash")
```

By applying map to your DataFrame twitterdata you have transformed it from shape  `(String, String, String, String, String)` to shape `(Boolean, Boolean, String, String)` - is that what you want?

`if(matchmonth.(r => (r(0))) < matchmonth.(r => (r(1)))` is not valid syntax.

To get started you want to select the rows that match your month range. This will return another DataFrame. From there I will leave it to you to read up on spark sql. groupBy and sum will probably help you

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

val filteredDf = twitterdata.where($"month" >= lit(x) && $"month" <= lit(y))
```